# $K=F_3(t)$ show that for every root $\alpha$ of the polynomial $f(x)=x^6-tx^3+1$, $K(\alpha)/K$ is a splliting field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-extensions

$K=F_3(t)$ show that for every root $\alpha$ of the polynomial $f(x)=x^6-tx^3+1 \in K[x] $   ,    $K(\alpha)/K$ is a splitting field.

By putting $u=x^3$ I showed that we have two roots (because either $t=\pm 2$ but $\pm 2 \in F_3 $ so $t$ cannot extend $F_3$)
for every $a\in F_3$ I know that $x^3=x$, but this condition doesn't refer tor $t$.

So how could I show that this extension is splitting with one of the roots $\alpha$ ?

Comment: Possible confusion. I think $t$ is transcendental over $\Bbb{F}_3$ here. So I don't understand what you mean by "either $t=\pm2$"?

Comment: Anyway, the idea with $u=x^3$ is great! This polynomial has two distinct roots, both with multiplicity three. Can you figure out a relation between them? Something that guarantees the inclusion of the other if you adjoin the other?

Comment: Hint: By expanding $f(1/x)$ we see that $$x^6f(1/x)=f(x),$$ so if $f(\alpha)=0$ then $f(1/\alpha)=????$

Comment: Note that $(a+b)^3=a^3+b^3$ even if $a,b$ are from an extension field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observe that $$\begin{align}f(x)&=x^6+2tx^3+1\\&=(x^3+t)^2+1-t^2\\&=(x^3+t-\sqrt{t^2-1})(x^3+t+\sqrt{t^2-1})\\&=(x+\sqrt[3]{t-\sqrt{t^2-1}})^3(x+\sqrt[3]{t+\sqrt{t^2-1}})^3\end{align}$$
This means that $f$ has only two roots $\alpha,\beta$ and they satisfy $(\alpha+\beta)^3=\alpha^3+\beta^3=2t$.

If $f(\alpha)=0$, then $2t=\frac{\alpha^6+1}{-\alpha^3}=((\alpha^2+1)/2\alpha)^3$. This means that $\sqrt[3]{2t}\in K(\alpha)$.

But then $\beta=\sqrt[3]{2t}-\alpha\in K(\alpha)$.

Comment: This works also (+1).

Comment: Oh, and $\alpha^3+\beta^3=-2t=t$, and then $t=\frac{\alpha^6+1}{\alpha^3}$ etc.

Comment: I still think that a slightly simpler way to get $\beta$ is to use $\alpha^3\beta^3=1\implies\alpha\beta=1$ :-)