# finding $[K(α):K] $, and $\operatorname{Aut}(K(α)/K)$ when $K=F_3(t)$ and $α$ is root of the polynomial $f(x)=x^6−tx^3+1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

in the previous post:[$K=F_3(t)$ show that for every root $\alpha$ of the polynomial $f(x)=x^6-tx^3+1$, $K(\alpha)/K$ is a splliting field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2784219/k-f-3t-show-that-for-every-root-alpha-of-the-polynomial-fx-x6-tx31?noredirect=1#comment5741752_2784219)  I proof that $K(\alpha)$ is splitting field over $K$ when $\alpha$ is root of the polynomial $f\in K[x]$
now I need to know what is $[K(\alpha):K]$ and $\operatorname{Aut}(K(\alpha)/K)$

I assume that because $f$ is a 6 degree minimal polynomial in $K$ so
$[K(\alpha):K]=6$
and because I have only 2 roots for $f$ so
$\operatorname{Aut}(K(\alpha)/K)=(Id, \sigma)\to \sigma (\alpha)=\beta , \sigma (\beta)=\alpha$
when $\alpha,\beta$ are roots of the polynomial $f$.
Am I right?

Comment: Everything looks correct to me (+1). I'm just trying to come up with a sleek way of proving that $f(x)$ is irreducible over $K$

Comment: Assume $f=pq$. We can assume that $p,q$ are relatively prime. Then $0=f'=p'q+pq'$. This implies that $p|p'$. This cannot be because of the degrees, unless $p'=0$ and therefore $q'=0$. This means that $p(x)=p_0(x^3)$ and $q(x)=q_0(x^3)$, with $p_0,q_0\in F_3(t)[x]$. Then $h(x)=x^2+2tx+1=p_0(x)q_0(x)$. But this polynomial doesn't have roots in $F_3(t)$. Therefore, one of $p_0$ or $q_0$ is a constant, and so will be one of $p$ or $q$.

Comment: That's nice @fishroe! I decided to take the longer route not using derivatives (only uniqueness of factorization of polynomials).

Comment: Irreducibility of $f$ over $\Bbb F_3[t]$ is easy, @JyrkiLahtonen: Form $F(X-1)= X^6 +(1-t)X^3+t-1$, irreducible by Eisenstein, with respect to the prime $(t-1)$.

Comment: That's a nice way, @Lubin! Worth adding as an answer? Looks like I was too sold on isolating the separable intermediate extension.

Comment: Oy, @JyrkiLahtonen, I’ll think about it. Today’s a busy day. Tomorrow too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Your answers are correct. An ultra-detailed solution below just in case you need some of those steps, or want to see alternative arguments.

---

Let $g(x)=x^2-tx+1$, so $f(x)=g(x^3)$.

1. We first see that $g(x)$ is irreducible over $K$. This is because (complete the square!) $g(x)=(x+t)^2-(t^2-1)$ has no zeros in $K$. Namely, uniqueness of factorization in the polynomial ring $\Bbb{F}_3[t]$ tells that $t^2-1=(t-1)(t+1)$ is not the square of any rational function in $t$.
2. Let $u$ and $v$ be the zeros of $g(x)$. We then have the relations $u+v=t$, $uv=1$, so the field $L:=K(u)$ is the splitting field of $g(x)$ over $K$ and $[L:K]=2.$
3. We see that $t=u+v=u+1/u$ is actually an element of the the field $\Bbb{F}_3(u)$. It follows that $L=\Bbb{F}_3(u)$.
4. Uniqueness of factorization in the polynomial ring, only this time in $\Bbb{F}_3[u]$, again implies that $u$ cannot be a cube in the field $\Bbb{F}_3(u)$. Therefore it isn't a cube of any element of the field $L$.
   It follows that the polynomial $h(x)=x^3-u$ is irreducible over $L$.
5. If $\alpha$ is a zero of $h(x)$, then, by irreducibility of $h(x)$, $[L(\alpha):L]=3$. Because we are un characteristic three, we have $$h(x)=(x-\alpha)^3.$$
6. The element $\beta=1/\alpha\in L$ satisfies the equation 
   $$\beta^3=1/\alpha^3=1/u=v,$$ so $$g(x)=(x-\alpha^3)(x-\beta^3)$$ and therefore $$f(x)=g(x^3)=(x^3-\alpha^3)(x^3-\beta^3)=(x-\alpha)^3(x-\beta)^3.$$ This means that $L(\alpha)$ is the splitting field of $f(x)$ over $K$. Because $u=\alpha^3$ we also see that $L(\alpha)=K(\alpha)$.
7. The tower of extensions $K\subset L\subset L(\alpha)$ gives, by multiplicativity of the extension degree, that $[K(\alpha):K]=[L(\alpha):K]=6$. Consequently $f(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K$. In particular, it is irreducible over $K$.
8. Any $K$-automorphism $\tau$ of $K(\alpha)$ is uniquely determined by $\tau(\alpha)$. As $\alpha$ and $\beta=1/\alpha$ are the only zeros of $f(x)$, there are exactly two automorphisms. The identity mapping, the $K$-automorphism interchanging $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: It may be worth observing that the splitting field $K(\alpha)=\Bbb{F}_3(\alpha)$. In other words, all the fields $K, K(u)$ and $K(\alpha)$ are isomorphic to the field of rational functions, and hence to each other!

Comment: In a general way why $u$ cannot be a cube over the field $F_3(u)$ its very intuative but I need formal explanation,and how its related to  Uniqueness of factorization in the polynomial ring?

Comment: @DanielVainshtein The elements of $\Bbb{F}_3(u)$ are of the form $z=p(u)/q(u)$ where $p,q$ are coprime polynomials. If $z^3=u$, then we get $u q(u)^3=p(u)^3$ implying that $u$ must be a factor of $p(u)$. But then $u^3$ is a factor of $p(u)^3$ implying in turn that $u$ is also a factor of $q(u)$ in violation of the coprime assumption. In other words, the argument is totally analogous to a standard proof of irrationality of $\sqrt2$.